# What is meaning of below "'Cron timing "?

Tags: magento-1.9

Please help me for understanding below cron timing because I have no idea about cron timing. (magento 1.9.3.0)

```
<schedule><cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>

<schedule><cron_expr>*/12 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>

<schedule><cron_expr>0 8 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>

<schedule><cron_expr>0,30 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cron task an automated task on a server run on a scheduled timer based on the server clock. The server clock tells the task when to run. CRON timing is designated in 5 increments; minutes, hours, days, months, weekdays (each * is an increment)

```
* * * * * = every minute
*/12 * * * * = every 12 minutes
* */1 * * * = every hour
0 8 * * * = 8th (8am) hour of the day
0,30 * * * * = every 30 minutes or exactly the same as 0/30 * * * *
```

Comment: Eirik thank you :)